# Bash looping through array - get index

Tags: bash, loops, indexing, match

I have seen many answers to looping through an array in bash so that you not only get the index, but also the variable *at* that index. For example

```
for i in "${!foo[@]}"; do 
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$i" "${foo[$i]}"
done
```

However, for my variable *foo*, this is defined as:

```
foo=$(< varlist.txt)
```

Where varlist.txt is a simple 10 row textfile consisting of a 4-letter code on each line. When I try the above method, the output is not matching up. What am I missing here?

For example:

vi varlist.txt

```
 QOP1
 QOP2
 LMA1
 LMA2
 NKO1
 NKO2
 POZ1
 POZ2
 CCS1
 CCS2
```

vi file_to_test.txt

```
 #text
 #more header text
 POZ1
 CCS2
```

The output should be:

```
 7 POZ1
 10 CCS2
```

As these are the 7th and 10th index from the varlist file.

Comment: Your variable is not an array, it's a single string that happens to contain newlines. If you have bash version 4 or later, try defining it with `readarray -t foo < varlist.txt` instead.

Comment: ...or, in bash 3: `foo=(); while IFS= read -r line; do foo+=( "$line" ); done <varlist.txt`, or `IFS=$'\n' read -r -d '' -a foo <varlist.txt ||:` (with the caveat that that'll cut off input at the first NUL, and won't retain exit status for genuine read errors).